# Como Crear una directiva custom - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-directivas

Creé una directiva custom en *angular*, y quiero compartir un valor entre mi directiva y mi archivo *typescript*, este es un ejemplo de mis 2 archivos:

```
<!-- Mi html --> 
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='lightgreen'">Green
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='yellow'">Yellow
  <input type="radio" name="colors" (click)="color='cyan'">Cyan
</div>
<p [appHighlight]="color">Highlight me!</p>
<p *ngIf="color">True</p>

<p [appHighlight]="color" defaultColor="violet">
  Highlight me too!
</p>

 <!-- mi typescript --> 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  color: boolean;
}
```

---

```
<!-- mi directiva custom -->
/* tslint:disable:member-ordering */
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  @Input() color: boolean;
  @Input() defaultColor: boolean;

  @Input('appHighlight') highlightColor: string;

  @HostListener('mouseenter')
  onMouseEnter() {
    console.log(this.color);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
  }

  private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

Al cambiar el valor booleano a `true` o `false`, mi *`ngIf` lo evalúa y me muestra el `<p *ngIf="color">True</p>` debidamente.

Pero al cambiar el valor en mi directiva `*ngIf` no lo evalúa, cómo puedo comunicar el valor de mi directiva con mi `.ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que tu directiva pueda no solo recibir sino también enviar valores tenés que usar `@Output`.

Si te fijás en tu código tenés `@Input` para cosas que van a entrar en la directiva, `@Output` sirve para sacar.

En tu caso tendrías que definir tu variable de salida como un `EventEmitter`, y cuando querrás emitir un valor usas el método `emit`.

```
  @Output() colorOut = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('mouseleave')
  onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
    this.colorOut.emit(null);
  }
```

Y en tu componente, en la plantilla HTML debes usar el evento de salida, el valor emitido estará en `$event`:

```
<p [appHighlight]="color" (colorOut)="color = $event">Highlight me!</p>
```

Comment: Gracias @Nery, sirvió de mucha ayuda...

Comment: @Nery Ortez , disculpa, una directiva se podría usar para aplicar una lógica (que no tenga que ver con la manipulación del DOM) a un componente? la idea es, suscribirme al evento navigationEnd del router desde al app.component.html que es donde tengo el <router-outlet> , hacer unas operaciones, y luego hacer algo como esto <router-outelet [customDirective]> </router-outelet> , entonces cada componente que se cargue, tendrá la lógica aplicada de la directiva, es eso posible ?

Comment: @julianprog No se si entiendo la pregunta. Pero puedes abrir una pregunta en SO, para dar más detalle de lo que cabe en un comentario